# Swagger Core Jersey 2.X Project Setup 1.5

Tags: rest, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am facing an issue while integrating swagger in my project. I integrated swagger (as [described](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5)) in my existing jersey api and deployed on weblogic server. As there are different modules so there already few jars available in weblogic and due to it I am facing conflicts issues. Below is detailed description about what I have done.

pom.xml

```
<dependency> <groupId>io.swagger</groupId> <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId> <version>1.5.0</version> </dependency>
```

DemoApplication.java

```
public class DemoApplication extends ResourceConfig {

public DemoApplication() {
    super(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class,io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    configSwagger();
}

private void configSwagger() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/demo/rest/v1");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage(DemoApplication.class.getPackage().getName());
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
```

}

And my sample Resource class is like

```
@Path("/ping")
@Api(tags = {"/ping"})
public class DemoServiceV1 {

//some code 


}
```

While I deploy the app on weblogic it gives exception as

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer

I tried to figure it out and found that there are two different version jars in weblogic module for

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind_2.3.2.jar

and

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind_2.4.3.jar

and weblogic picks

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind_2.3.2.jar

by defaults which does not have findPropertyIndex method.
I even tried by keeping the above jar i.e. com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind_2.3.2.jar in APP-INF/lib but still it do not load the jar.

Can any one help in above issue? Swagger integration is totally new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try weblogic tool (wls-cat) to find out JARs conflicts. You can browse using this URL http://localhost:port/wls-cat/ . This tool will help you understand whether your JARs are properly loaded or not. If there is conflict, it can tell you in which JAR. By using this tool you can also define JARs priority to load.
Hope this helps.

Comment: CAT is a stand-alone Web application, distributed as a single WAR file (WL_HOME/server/lib/wls-cat.war). It is deployed as an internal on-demand application only in development mode and the deployment happens upon first access. If the server is running in production mode, it is not deployed automatically but you can deploy it manually, just like any other Web application.